# How to give synonyms to an employee name lookup table?

Tags: lookup-tables, synonym, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I have created a lookup table of employee name text file referring to the rasa blog(link below).

[Improving entity extractions with Rasa](https://blog.rasa.com/improving-entity-extraction/)

Now my use case also requires me to give synonyms to these employees in the lookup table. For example, “Nicholas” can also be referred to as “Nick” or “Nic”, so that the rasa bot can extract “nick” as “nicholas” and fulfill the use case.

Please advice how to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Lookup and synonyms have a different purpose as while, lookups are used for entity extraction, synonyms are used as a filtration method to change the format of any synonyms to original text. Therefore, I think, you can't have synonyms within the lookup table so you might have to do that separately.

However, If you have a long list of synonyms you can use a file path instead of list.

```
## synonym:Nick
data/path/nick.txt
```

I had a similar situation with City names and their nick while I was using City name from the lookup but placed their synonyms in the main data file as

```
## synonym:New York City
- NY
- NYC
- New York

## lookup:city
  data/lookups/city_lookup.txt
```

I recommend using https://github.com/rodrigopivi/Chatito which will really ease the task for you as it has a really good mapping system that does the work for you with regards to synonyms and lookups.

Comment: this doesn't work from me in rasa latest version, apparent the the synonyms are not applied before the lookup and hence returns none

Comment: super example, thanks!